# How should HTTP server respond to 'If-Match' header when it's unsupported yet?

Tags: http, rest

I have an HTTP server implementation with partial REST support.  It doesn't support `If-Match` and `If-None-Match` yet but I am going to implement it eventually, just not in this release.

In this case, what response should the HTTP server when a client sends an HTTP PUT request with `If-Match` or `If-None-Match` header?  Ignoring them and just updating the resource don't sound right because the client obviously wants the server *not* to update the resource.

What response the server should send then?  I think the server at least should tell the client that those headers are not supported and thus the request has been rejected.  Is there any status code dedicated to this sort of responses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[501 Not Implemented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error)

Comment: Doh! You're right.  Too bad that I can only accept in 10 minutes. :-)